# Keep checkbox checked after navigating away from page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a check box that I need to keep checked after navigating away from the page. I am using AngularJS and bootstrap.  Right now I am resetting the bound variable to false every time I reload the page (when the controller runs): how can I store my most up to date variable (`$scope.disableCheck`)?

In my controller....

```
$scope.disableCheck = false;
$scope.removeCheck = function () {
   $scope.disableCheck = !$scope.disableCheck;
}
```

And in my HTML...

```
<input class="notification-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{disableCheck}}" ng-click="removeCheck()" ng-clicked="{{disableCheck}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using $rootScope instead. It is global to all controllers

Something like this

```
.controller('someCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.disableCheck = true;//set root scope here and refer to it as needed from other controlers
})
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I would use it? Thanks!

Comment: I made an edit to the answer. Angular can inject rootscope if you ask for it in the controller

Comment: Thanks! I also used this fiddle to help me out for anyone else http://jsfiddle.net/TmPk5/6/